# WPF RichTextBox font scaled by 3/4

Tags: wpf, richtextbox

I have a WPF RichTextBox which I want to let the user change the font size on:

```
void SetFontSize(double size)
{
    var selection = richTextBox.Selection;
    if (selection.IsEmpty)
        richTextBox.FontSize = size;
    else
        selection.ApplyPropertyValue(RichTextBox.FontSizeProperty, size);
}
```

In the real world scenario, it's embedded in a System.Windows.Forms.Integration.ElementHost() and should be inheriting the font from its WinForms parent, but I can reproduce this issue in a 100% WPF scenario.

The problem is that the font size seems to be 3/4 as large as what was set.  So the WinForms font is 8.5, and it converts that to 11 1/3.  If I read back the font size, it claims it's 11.33333, but if I copy and paste the text into wordpad, it says the font size is 8.5.

If I try to reset the font back to match the parent control's 8.5, it then sets it to 3/4 of that, which is 6.375, too small to read.  I would have to set it to 4/3 * 8.5 to get it to match the WinForms font size.

I call the sample code above with 10.0, and then copy the text into wordpad, and it says I have 7.5 point font.  And so forth.

I don't have any UI scaling going on.  Windows screen resolution is set at 100%.   I overrode the ScaleCore in the ElementHost parent control and put a breakpoint, and it shows that the scaling is set at 1:1.

Why is it scaling everything 3/4?  Is that a universal constant that I should just multiply and divide by whenever I read/write the font size from this control?

Comment: Now that stackoverflow has had a chance to connect to related questions, I see this similar question: 
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301397/font-size-mismatch-between-richtextbox-and-word?rq=1  but the main difference is that they're setting it in Xaml, and I'm trying to set it programatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `FontSize` you specify should be in DIPs (device-independent pixels).

- https://www.codeproject.com/articles/43520/device-independent-units-to-points-to-inches.aspx
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.fontsize(v=vs.110).aspx

When the `RichTextBox` is given a size it calculates/maps it back to the nearest point size to use.

Thus you need to do a calculation that will calculate a DIP value, which will end up giving you your desired "PointSize" in the `RichTextBox`.

```
double sizeindips = (double) new FontSizeConverter().ConvertFrom("8.5pt");
```

This is effectively what is called underneath by a "converter" when a size is specified with the "pt" suffix in XAML.

Comment: So just to be clear, System.Drawing.Font size is in "pt" units, and needs to be converted using the code above?

Comment: Also, it very not obvious how to convert back from "11.333333" to "8.5pt" using the FontSizeConverter.  I guess I can just save the conversion factor going the other direction and invert it.  Is there a more appropriate way?

Comment: 1  DIP always = 1/96 inch..... 72 points = 1 inch. Therefore: points = (dips / 96) * 72;